# Matrices as a linear map - subspace problem

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, solution-verification

Consider a linear transformation from $F^4$ to $F^3$ given by the matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1&3\\1&1&2&4\\1&1&1&3\end{pmatrix}$.

Describe the kernel $Ker(A)\subset F^4$ and the image $Im(A)\subset F^3$ by writing each as the span of linearly independent vectors.

To do this, I said that we need to find $(a,b,c,d)$ such that $\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1&3\\1&1&2&4\\1&1&1&3\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$.

This translates to the system of equations :

$$a+b+c+3d=0 \ \ \ \ \ (i)$$
$$a+b+2c+4d=0 \ \ \ \ \ (ii)$$

This forces $c=-d$. As such our general solution is given by $\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\\-c\end{pmatrix}$, and a basis for the kernel is $\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\\-1\end{pmatrix}$. Now my problem is that the dimension is $2$ which cannot be the basis for a 4D subspace. How do I rectify this? Or have I used the completely wrong method?

Comment: You can't just forget about both of the original equations, since they aren't implied by $c=-d$.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: You are correct that $c=-d$ has to hold for all solutions, but equations (i) and (ii) still have to hold as well. Which you didn't consider at all when giving the general solution.

Comment: You're right - thanks for pointing this out! I will work on solving this fully now

Comment: Who says the kernel is four dimensional? It wouldn't make much sense if it was, that would force $A = 0$ which clearly isn't the case.

Answer (score 1):

We also have $a+b+c-3c=0$, i.e. $b=2c-a$, so every element in the kernel is of the form $(a,2c-a,c,-c)$. You can therefore take
$$\{(1,-1,0,0),(0,2,1,-1)\}$$
as a basis.

Comment: Surely every basis has equal dimension?

Comment: Yes, the kernel is 2 dimensional since we can express $b$ and $d$ in terms of $a$ and $c$.

Comment: Ah nice - I got confused but I think I get it now!